# Can href be an ID?

Tags: javascript, html, href

I'm learning about `JavaScript` from an `udemy` tutorial and I try to make API calls. There is a website about recipes and I make API calls. And I have a misunderstanding because until now I knew that an `href` is a link, not a number.

This is a piece of code from index.html and the `href` is an id:

```
<li>
  <a class="results__link results__link--active" href="#23456">
    <figure class="results__fig">
         <img src="img/test-1.jpg" alt="Test">
    </figure>
    <div class="results__data">
         <h4 class="results__name">Pasta with Tomato ...</h4>
         <p class="results__author">The Pioneer Woman</p>
    </div>
 </a>
</li>
```

And this is a recipe list that I receive if I make an `API` call and I need to put the recipe_id which is a number in the `href`. And I don't understand how can I put a number in the `href`

[image]

Comment: You can use a number as a component of the url as either a folder, file or query parameter, so long as the server understands it.

Comment: Generally a `href` is a link to a page. But a `href`can also be can `id`or the combination of both, so your browser automatically scrolls to the specific `id`

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If the `href` is a `#` flowed by an element id it is what is called an anchor link. It will get you to the element with the given id in the same page. You can read more about it [here](https://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/link/html-anchor-link.html).

Answer (score 0):

> Can a href be an ID?

**In short, Yes.**

`href` doesn't necessarily always mean an external link, it could link to an element on the current `html` page, which from the example you have provided i think this is the case.

If you map your recipe_id as a `id` to an element in your page, and you then say reference the recipe_id as a `href` when you click your `href` the page should scroll / navigate to the element with that id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a number as a hyperlink, in this case anyway.

The # means it is referring to an element with that id on the page. To my knowledge it is only classes that you cannot use a number at the beginning without escaping it.

You are also able to leave the current page and go to an element on a different page. You can do this by tailing your #id on to the url string you are used to seeing.

If you give more background into the project we might be able to give less vague answers.